# Create pairwise data frame from two columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have some sample data

```
df = data.frame("cus" = c("cus1", "cus1", "cus1", "cus1", "cus2", "cus2", "cus2", 
"cus3", "cus3"), "prod"=c("prod1", "prod2", "prod3", "prod4", "prod5", "prod1", 
"prod2", "prod3", "prod4"))
```

and I would like to create a new data frame which has unique(df$cus) as rownames and unique(df$prod) as colnames. Then the value should be either 1 if the combination cusX - prodX is in df or 0 if it is not.
The desired output looks like this:

```
     prod1 prod2 prod3 prod4 prod5
cus1     1     1     1     1     0
cus2     1     0     0     0     1
cus3     0     0     1     1     0
```

Does anybody have a idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table` does that:

```
> table(df)
      prod
cus    prod1 prod2 prod3 prod4 prod5
  cus1     1     1     1     1     0
  cus2     1     1     0     0     1
  cus3     0     0     1     1     0
```

… but in itself it doesn’t return a `data.frame` (instead it returns a matrix of class `table`). If you actually need a `data.frame`, then `as.data.frame(table(df))` works, but is probably not what you want:

```
> as.data.frame(table(df))
      cus   prod  Freq
 1   cus1  prod1     1
 2   cus2  prod1     1
 3   cus3  prod1     0
 4   cus1  prod2     1
 …
```

This is because it’s *usually* more sensible to perform this conversion. To avoid doing so, you need to un-set the `class` of the table:

```
result = as.data.frame(unclass(table(df)))
```

Comment: You can do this to get the data.frame in one step: `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))`

Comment: @Pierre: True, but you’re not generally supposed to call S3 generics directly. In fact, nowadays it’s discouraged to even *export* them when writing packages. `base` is using outdated practices in this regard.